# I need help displaying the output of a PHP script into a DIV tag ontop of an image

Tags: php, css, html

I would like to display folder contents on top of the image "folderContents05.jpg" inside of it's DIV tag. The PHP script should output the folder contents of the directory it resides in.  The script works fine by itself, but I can't seem to get anything to display when I use it in html, or call the script.

Here is the HTML-

```
<head>
<title>index</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- End Save for Web Styles -->
</head>
<body style="background-color:#353535; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (index.psd) -->
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="Table_01">
<div id="folderContents01">
<img src="images/folderContents01.jpg" width="359" height="120" alt="">
</div>
<div id="folderContents02">
<img src="images/folderContents02.jpg" width="591" height="150" alt="">
</div>
<div id="folderContents03">
<img src="images/folderContents03.jpg" width="359" height="30" alt="">
</div>
<div id="folderContents04">
<img src="images/folderContents04.jpg" width="126" height="460" alt="">
</div>
<div id="folderContents05">
<img src="images/folderContents05.jpg" width="698" height="396" alt="">
</div>
<div id="folderContents06">
<img src="images/folderContents06.jpg" width="126" height="460" alt="">
</div>
<div id="folderContents07">
<img src="images/folderContents07.jpg" width="698" height="64" alt="">
</div>
<div id="folderContents08">
<img src="images/folderContents08.jpg" width="950" height="90" alt="">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

and the php script

```
<?php
$count = 0;
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {$count++;
print("<a href=\"".$file."\">".$file."</a><br />\n");
}
}
closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Where are you calling the PHP code from your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the "folder content" images as a background to your div and generate the HTML markup by php itself something like the code below

```
if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {$count++;
print(<div id="folderContents +i">
</div>)
```

and put a counter so you can use it to generate ( folderContents1 , folderContents2, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Use `style= "z-index: 0"` on your `<img>` tags and change the PHP to this:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
echo '<div style="z-index: 1">';
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {$count++;
print("<a href=\"".$file."\">".$file."</a><br />\n");
}
}
echo '</div>';
closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Using the z-index establishes an order of 'on-top-ness' for elements

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
<div id="folderContents05" style="position: relative">
  <img src="images/folderContents05.jpg" width="698" height="396" alt="">
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 100">
  <?php
   $count = 0;
   if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
     while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
       if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
         $count++;
         print("<a href=\"".$file."\">".$file."</a><br />\n");
       }
     }
   closedir($handle);
   }
  ?>
  </div>
</div>
```